# Does this submit function need to be in a document ready call? Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a site which I don't have full access to so I can't do PHP.

```
    $( "#contact_form" ).submit(function() {
        $("#contact_form").find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

Comment: all jQuery codes must be inside a dom ready function!

Comment: Try it and find out?

Answer (score 0):

It is always preferable to put your jQuery code inside a $(document).ready(), as it prevents the code from being executed when the targeted DOM nodes are still not loaded.